# R predict.glm when newdata has fewer levels

Tags: r, regression, glm, predict

I attempted to prove to myself that `predict()` will not give incorrect predictions, when labels and levels (the underlying integer for the factor level) of `newdata` do not match that of the train data.

I think I did prove that, and I'm sharing that code below, but I'd just like to ask what exactly R is doing when predicting for `newdata`.  I know it is not appending `newdata` to training data, does it translate the factor labels of `newdata` into the corresponding representation of train data before predicting?

```
options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(c("cat", "dog", "bird", "horse"), 100), y = rgamma(100, shape=3,  scale = 300))
model <- glm(y~., family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = dat)

coefficients(model)
# (Intercept)        xcat        xdog      xhorse 
#   6.5816536   0.2924488   0.3586094   0.2740487 

newdata1 <- data.frame(x = "cat")
newdata2 <- data.frame(x = "bird")
newdata3 <- data.frame(x = "dog")

predict.glm(object = model, newdata = newdata1, type = "response")
#       1 
# 966.907 
exp(6.5816536 + 0.2924488) #intercept + cat coef
# [1] 966.9071

predict.glm(object = model, newdata = newdata2, type = "response")
#        1 
# 721.7318 
exp(6.5816536)
# [1] 721.7318

predict.glm(object = model, newdata = newdata3, type = "response")
#        1 
# 1033.042 
exp(6.5816536 + 0.3586094)
# [1] 1033.042

unclass(dat$x)
#  [1] 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3
# [87] 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4
# [173] 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3
# [259] 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4
# [345] 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "bird"  "cat"   "dog"   "horse"

unclass(newdata1$x)
# [1] 1
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "cat"

unclass(newdata2$x)
# [1] 1
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "bird"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model object has an `xlevels` recording factor levels used for model estimation. For your example, we have:

```
model$xlevels
#$x
#[1] "bird"  "cat"   "dog"   "horse"
```

When your new data is presented in prediction, factor levels will be matched. For example, your `newdata1` will be matched to "cat" levels, and this is the second level in `xlevels`. Thus, predict will have no difficulty finding the correct coefficients for that level.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't find how to accept the answer but this is what I needed.